# Induction Proof in Algorithms

Tags: algorithm

Assume an arbitrary `r`

```
T(n) <= cn + T(n/r) + T (3n/4)
```

show `T(n) <= Dcn` for some constant `D`

by reworking the induction proof, use the expression to argue that:

`T(n) <= Dcn` does not hold for `r=3`.

Comment: its from text which i cant figure it out and i have a exam coming up so i need to understand this

Comment: So we should show that T(n) <= Dcn for arbitrary r but at the same time argue that T(n) <= Dcn does not hold for r=3 ?

Comment: yes i think so we need to use that

Comment: The base cases are missing in the question - when does the recursion stop? I assume it may be `T(1) = c`. Further note that `n` must be divisible by `r` and 4 in every step - this constraints valid values for `n` quite a bit.

Comment: Or is the equation missing some rounding? Should it be `T(floor(n/r))` and `T(floor(3n/4))`?

Comment: @Nick - Shouldn't that be: Argue that: `T(n) <= Dcn` does not hold for `D=3` ?

Comment: @Peter: I believe the r=3 is correct, but the earlier part is incomplete. Perhaps it is: For r > 4, T(n) <= Dcn. For r <= 4, there is not such D. (Just a guess).

Comment: @Moron: You may be right. The OP should update the question. In it's present form it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Akra-Bazzi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra-Bazzi_method). This is a generalization of the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) that does not require subproblems of equal size.

Comment: but we havent taught that by Prof. yet

Comment: Yep. That's it. The induction method and a few examples here: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mehlhorn/DatAlg2008/NewMasterTheorem.pdf